# Как определить, что контрол в переменной - это ScrolledText?

Tags: python, tkinter

В данном примере удаляются только виджеты классов Entry и Label. Но еще надо, чтобы удалялись и ScrolledText. Как их удалить?

```
def dele(event): # удаление виджетов
    for w in root.winfo_children():
        if w.winfo_class() == 'Entry': w.destroy()
    for w in root.winfo_children():
        if w.winfo_class() == 'Label': w.destroy()
    for w in root.winfo_children():
        if w.winfo_class() == 'ScrolledText': w.destroy()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: решение больше не требуется, обозначил как  if w.winfo_class() == 'Frame': w.destroy(), и все теперь работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `ScrolledText` `winfo_class() == 'Frame'` (т.к. он создан на основе фрейма, в котором лежит текстовое поле и полосы прокрутки). Просто проверяйте тип самих объектов, а не `winfo_class`:

```
for w in root.winfo_children():
    if isinstance(w, Entry): w.destroy()
    if isinstance(w, Label): w.destroy()
    if isinstance(w, ScrolledText): w.destroy()
```